# CLI softwareupdate does not find updates

Tags: command-line, software-update

I can see in the App Store that I have one application (Xcode 5.0.2) that needs to be updated. But if I run the `sudo softwareupdate --list` in terminal I get the message that there is "No new software available". Why don't the CLI tool and the App Store have the same information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The CLI tool `softwareupdate` is only for OS X updates provided through Apple's software update catalog, or whichever .sucatalog is set in preferences for catalogs provided by OS X Server's Software Update service.

This update catalog does not contain details for Mac App Store apps, such as Xcode.

---

You can restrict the Mac App Store to only show `softwareupdate` updates by running the following Terminal command:

```
defaults write com.apple.appstore restrict-store-softwareupdate-only -bool yes
```

You can read more about the `softwareupdate` CLI tool in the [man page](http://cl.ly/SPxT).